# What happens if a batter accidentally hits the ball twice?

Tags: rules, cricket

What happens if a batter accidentally, and as part of once action, hits the ball twice while playing shot? Will it be regarded as a normal shot, no runs or out?

If it makes a difference, the double hit happens before the ball touches the ground.

Answer (score 2):

*Accidentally* hitting the ball twice as part of one motion has no effect on the game - runs are eligible to be scored as normal. There's nothing specific in the Laws of Cricket about this, other than to note that [Law 34 Hit the ball twice](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/hit-the-ball-twice) refers specifically to the striker **willfully** striking the ball twice, and there is no mention in e.g. [Law 20 Dead ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/dead-ball) of the ball becoming dead if it is accidentally hit twice.